# Передать в action значение из формы

Tags: php, action

Добрый день. Не силен в тонкостях, подскажите как передать id в action, когда ставлю ручками поиск работает:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?page=search&locationid=" id="base-search-hotels-form" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="hidden" name="locationid" id="base-search-hotels-form-locationid" value="{if isset($currentLocation)}{$currentLocation[0]["id"]}{/if}"/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="base-search-location" placeholder="Направление" value="{if isset($currentLocation)}{$currentLocation[0]["locationname"]}{/if}" /><br>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="roomscount" id="base-search-roomscount" value="" placeholder="Спальных мест" />
    <label for="dateto" id="label-br">Дата заезда</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="dateto" name="dateto" />
    <label for="datefrom" id="label-br">Дата выезда</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefrom" name="datefrom" />                    
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="base-searchbtn" value="{$currentLocation[0]["id"]}">
    Найти
</button>
```

Comment: Какой id, в какой action.

Comment: С этого Input:   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="base-search-location" placeholder="Направление" value="{if isset($currentLocation)}{$currentLocation[0]["locationname"]}{/if}" /> В action="index.php?page=search&locationid=вот сюда положить то значение которое выбирается из формы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дата заезда
                        
                        Дата выезда

```
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="base-searchbtn" value="{$currentLocation[0]["id"]}">
                        Найти
                    </button>
```

Так все работает корреткно, только нужно пересмотреть пагинацию, проблема в ней

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте нужному `input`'у атрибут `name`: к примеру так:

```
<input type="text" name="locationid" ...>
```

А из `action` `locationid` вообще уберите и оставьте его вот таким:

```
action="index.php?page=search"
```

И самый первый `input` который `type="hidden"` тогда удалите.

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, что при выборе того или иного расположения должен из Input Направление, приходить id направления и падать в action="index.php?page=search&locationid=*сюда должно приходить значение из input*"

Comment: @Den, Вы понимаете, что строка параметров в action генерируется из полей формы при отправке? В action должен быть только путь к файлу обработки формы и все.

Comment: Теперь понимаю, но дело в том что при action в который будет вложен locationid, будет срабатывать пагинатор и будет работать выборка из базы согласна результата поля. Насколько я понял это невозможно в силу моего слабоумия в логике. Если я отправляю GET тогда он передает ID, вопрос можно ли в такое случае передать только locationid а не все параметры в строку браузера? Заранее благодарю за ответы)

Comment: @Den, Вот именно, что параметры передаваемые в action являются GET параметрами, а параметры с инпутов формы - POST, так как на это указывает атрибут method. В файлt обработки формы locationid считывается как $_GET['locationid']. Вам нужно всего лишь поменять на эту запись на $_POST['locationid'] и у вас все будет прекрасно работать.

Comment: Спасибо что ответили, по поводу файла обработки, там у меня идет проверка: if(isset($_GET["locationid"]))
        $smarty->assign('currentLocation',bookingLocationsGet($_GET["locationid"]));
    if(isset($_POST["locationid"]))
        $smarty->assign('currentLocation',bookingLocationsGet($_POST["locationid"]));
После того как сделал вот так: <input type="hidden" name="locationid" id="base-search-hotels-form-locationid" value="{if isset($currentLocation)}{$currentLocation[0]["id"]}{/if}"/>
Теперь приходит нужный массив, но теперь думаю как значение в строку бразуера положить

Comment: @Den, использовать `GET` запрос. Он не скрывает передаваемые параметры, а отображает их в строке браузера.

Comment: Klym спасибо что не бросаешь. Попробую объяснить полностью, чтобы понимать откуда ноги растут)))

Comment: Klym спасибо что не бросаешь. Попробую объяснить полностью, чтобы понимать откуда ноги растут)))
Начнем: при передаче GET --- http://127.0.0.1:1080/suite/index.php?locationid=1&roomscount=2&dateto=2016-12-20&datefrom=2016-12-25
получаю это! Тут идет загвоздка что у меня ориентир стоит на index.php?page=search
В будущем мне нужно будет все это, но на данное время мне нужно только locationid и roomscount.
в индексе я указал: $smarty->assign('hotels', getHotelsBySearchData($_POST["locationid"],$_POST["roomscount"]));
 $smarty->display('search_hotels.tpl');
Если

Comment: И еще JS функция которая собирает Ajax и постит. Также нужно не забывать что это все идет в пагинатор и он маслает весь объект

Comment: @Den, из ваших объяснений ничего не ясно, в чем собственно проблема?

Comment: Klym, вообщем без пагинации работает корректно и все летает, нужно будет пересмотреть пагинацию. Спасибо что не бросили))))